# Add rails index page to manifest for service worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, service-worker, webpacker, workbox

I add to my rails project webpacker, react and workbox with service worker. I send all requests from all controllers to one React component App.js.
Service worker cache all files from manifest: js and css. But there is no index.html file in manifest, so my app not work in offline mode (js and css works fine).

How to add generated index.html file to manifest for sw cache?